# CustomView Styling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a problem with styling customview.
I'd like to use different styles in different layouts. But my styles aren't applied.

**CustomView layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
        <ImageView 
                   android:id="@+id/img"                       
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView 
                  android:id="@+id/txt"     
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
              android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"               
</merge>
```

**Definition in another layout:**

```
<com.buka.customviews.Bukaview
         android:id="@+id/bukaId"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             style="@style/BukaStyle1">
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="BukaStyle1">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="BukaStyle2">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom attribute : 
`<attr name="BukaStyleTextSize" format="dimensions" />` 
Then in the `TextView` tag of your custom view layout, put : 
`android:textSize="?attr:BukaStyleTextSize"`
And finally, in your styles in `styles.xml` put : 
`<item name="BukaStyleTextSize>10sp</item>`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the problem is that I'm defining attr BukaStyleTextSize on TextView but applying style on BukaView. Any ideas?

Comment: I think so too. Can you pass the attribute from your BukaView to the TextView in the java class ? And why don't you use a TextView with a drawableLeft or drawableTop ?

Comment: Actually i have more complicated layout and I need to set many params like size/color and others to TextView in it. I can't set style from attr in code.